# Simple PGF example of plotting a line on Cartesian plane and shadowing the area below this line

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm paging through the endless PGF manual looking to find a simple way of plotting a line and shadowing the area below it with no success so far. I would appreciate if you provide an example achieving this task which would serve as a good starting point for me to graph with PGF.

Thank you

Comment: Anyway, please provide what you try so far (even without shadowing).

Comment: How about [these](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/tag/filling/)? Otherwise, try looking through [these examples](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) using from the pgfplots manual.

Comment: Thank you for responding. It is great to see so many examples in one place without extra information clogging up large space between each of them (like in the manual). I have already spotted some that look promising for my task. Thank you.

Comment: That's because you seem to have been looking in the wrong manual. `pgfplots` is the manual you probably want.